# Web Worker in Angular not working - request not found

Tags: angular, web-worker

I followed angular web working tutorial and have been looking for this solution for a long time.

Component

main.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
      if (typeof Worker !== 'undefined') {
      // Create a new

      let worker = new Worker("./mapa-worker.worker", { type: "module" });

      console.log(worker)
      worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
        console.log(`page got message:`);
      };
      worker.postMessage('hello');
    } else {
      // Web workers are not supported in this environment.
      // You should add a fallback so that your program still executes correctly.
    }
}
```

and as tutorial said, my mapa-worker.worker.ts

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  const response = `worker response to ${data}`;
  postMessage(response);
});
```

[image]

With empty headers

[image]

[image]